# resolve dns lookup problems in webview

Tags: android, ios, webview, dns

Our company's app is mainly a webview embedded in the android/iPhone native app. In some area, the dns lookup always failed which results an error in opening our webview page.

We have found a technology called HttpDNS which can solve the pure native app's dns lookup problem, as it can send a http request by the ip(fetched from the HttpDNS) not domain, and set the domain of http header by hand. However in webview, we can't do that.

So is there a way to solve the dns problems in webview? Thank you (We found that we can set a proxy in app which can solve the dns lookup problems but this method is not so novel. ).

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Detect the page load failure and retry
- Provide a custom delegate that intercepts each request, performs the lookup, loads the content using NSURLConnection/NSURLSession, and then injects the content into the web view.

Neither approach is perfect, of course, as both are effective only if the user is loading a page that replaces the current page in the web view (as opposed to random XMLHTTPRequest calls).

And then, there's always:

- Swizzle NSURLConnection and NSURLSession, rewriting the request objects based on the result of your own lookup code, and overwriting the Host header field.

Although this does have the advantage of working even for XHR, I would tend to recommend against this approach for publicly distributed apps, though, for three reasons:

- Apple says not to touch the Host header field, which means future OS updates could break the behavior (assuming it even works).
- It is really easy to break things if you swizzle those classes incorrectly.
- It will change the way those classes behave for every request coming from your app, not just requests made by the web view.

Of course, you could avoid the first problem by adding libcurl and using that to perform the actual request, but then you're getting into seriously scary compatibility territory.  :-)

You might be better off trying to find out why the DNS lookup is failing.  Is it being blocked locally by an abusive ISP or government?  Can you add VPN technology to your app so that requests for your URL (and DNS lookups) get routed through a tunnel?

Comment: Thanks you very much. The VPN technology is a good way to avoid the dns problems. The ISP sucks in some rural area :-(